# Java url domain parsing with regex

Tags: java, regex

I want to parse a Url's domain (without 'www') with **regex** and return it. There are **many** examples for it on stackoverflow but they do not provide solution for all cases below or some of them has unneccessary features. My cases are:

```
http://www.google.co.uk      pass
http://www.google.co.uk      pass
http://google.com.co.uk      pass
same for https               pass
google.co.uk                 pass
www.google.co.uk             pass
```

and all must return only part of domain **google.co.uk** There is no need for links like 101.34.24.. or starting for fps etc... Only allowed input formats are at above. And i validate url with regex :
`^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?([\w]+\.)+[‌​\w]{2,63}\/?$` and it is working good but i do not know how to parse it.

Note: I would be happy if you do not recommend URI or URL classes and their methods for parsing domain automatically like:

```
private String parseUrl(String url) throws URISyntaxException {
        if (url.startsWith("http:/")) {
            if (!url.contains("http://")) {
                url = url.replaceAll("http:/", "http://");
            }
        } else if (url.startsWith("https:/")) {
            url = url.replaceAll("https:/", "http:/");
        } else {
            url = "http://" + url;
        }
        URI uri = new URI(url);
        String domain = uri.getHost();
        return domain.startsWith("www.") ? domain.substring(4) : domain;
    }
```

This code works perfectly as well but i need **regex** not this one.

Comment: Just curious: what is the use case that for you is better to use `regex` instead of the correct way of using an `URI/URL` parser.

Comment: just a brainless boss. is it valid reason? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex,

```
^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?([\w]+\.)+[‌​\w]{2,63}\/?$
```

matches the input but doesn't capture the intended domain in a group properly. You can modify it and make it simple like this,

```
^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?((?:[\w]+\.)+\w+)
```

which captures your intended domain capture in group 1.

**[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Gmojjc/1)**

Here is a sample Java code using extracts and prints domain name,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(?:https?:\\/\\/)?(?:www\\.)?((?:[\\w]+\\.)+\\w+)");
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("http://www.google.co.uk", "http://www.google.co.uk",
            "http://google.com.co.uk", "https://www.google.co.uk", "https://www.google.co.uk",
            "https://google.com.co.uk");

    list.forEach(x -> {
        Matcher m = p.matcher(x);
        if (m.matches()) {
            System.out.println(x + " --> " +m.group(1));
        }
    });
}
```

Prints,

```
http://www.google.co.uk --> google.co.uk
http://www.google.co.uk --> google.co.uk
http://google.com.co.uk --> google.com.co.uk
https://www.google.co.uk --> google.co.uk
https://www.google.co.uk --> google.co.uk
https://google.com.co.uk --> google.com.co.uk
```

Comment: thanks but when i try it no error comes but when i debug it goes to 'invocationtargetexception, and then  'java.lang.illegalstateexception: no match found' and not working :(

Comment: i have tried as you wrote (with println) it is working and parsing but when i use it with my code m.group is not working and throwing exception

Comment: ah works now. i have restarted ide and started to work. intellij bug

Comment: hey do you have any idea about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54330887/how-to-parse-url-domain-with-regex-in-java ? I just need parse the links including / and further parts as well

Comment: @abidinberkay: I was just reading your new post only :) Let me reply you there

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to add a capturing group to cover that section of the URL, `^(https?://)?(www\.)?(([\w]+\.)+[‌​\w]{2,63})/?$` would work here.

Beyond that, you just need to use a Matcher to grab the correct group (group 3 here):

```
private static Pattern URL_PATTERN =
        Pattern.compile("^(https?://)?(www\.)?(([\w]+\.)+[‌​\w]{2,63})/?$");

public static String minifyUrl(final String url) {
    final Matcher matcher = URL_PATTERN.matcher(url);
    if (matcher.find()) return matcher.group(3);
    else return url;
}
```

However, I still think you would be better served by using Java's URL class :p